# Angularjs: How to stream http response to new window?

Tags: angularjs

How can I use the angularjs `$http` service to post a request to the server and stream the result to a new browser window?

My service generates and streams back a pdf report which I'd like to open in a new browser window. So far I've been using `$http` to post requests which returned json data. I could use this to update the model. That works fine.  But now I don't want to extract data from the response, just display in another window. Perhaps I should be using a lower level service rather than the data exchange pattern I've been using?

```
$http(httpPostConfig).success(
    function(data, status, headers, config) {
        ...
    }
).error(

    function(data, status, headers, config) {
        ...
    }
);
```

Comment: Have your server return a unique identifier of the generated PDF and than use JS (through $window) service to open a new window with it's url pointing to a server-side endpoint which returns PDf based on unique identifier (e.g. `$window.open('/pdf/6234556')`).

Comment: @Stewie Thanks. If I can't figure out how to do it in an angular way, then I'll use a work around like this.

Comment: The thing is, your idea is not possible to implement the way you imagined it. There's neither an Angular or JS way of doing that. By the sound of your idea it seems to me that you're approaching this from a Java-based view of the world. Correct me if I'm wrong. ;-)

Comment: @Stewie You have me pegged correctly... I went ahead and implemented as suggested, using two requests. It seems a bit strange to me, but it works. If you put your comment as an answer I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have your server return a unique identifier of the generated PDF and than use $window service to open a new window with it's url pointing to a server-side endpoint which returns PDf based on unique identifier (e.g. `$window.open('/pdf/6234556')`);

Comment: any advice on how to create the "dynamic" server-side endpoint?