# Submit angularjs $http request to download document

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers

I want to submit a request via AngularJS $http.get or $http.post to download a file. I have ensured that the response contains the response contains the relevant content-disposition header values to ensure that the users browser automatically downloads the file instead of treating  it as a normal response. It works fine if I use window.location, but doesn't work via $http.get.

The reason I desperately want to use $http.get preferably $http.post is so that I append the X-XSRF-TOKEN to the request, thereby adding security.

Comment: you cannot use `$http.get` because javascript is not allowed to access local files system.

Comment: My file isn't actually a local file, The response content included the file content as Stream data

Comment: when you download a file, you need to save the stream (bytes) to local files system. Javascript is not allowed to access local files, therefore you cannot download files with javascript

Comment: My question is pretty similar to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345465/angularjs-how-to-stream-http-response-to-new-window), however I'm not entirely satisfied with the answer

Comment: @KhanhTO can we look at it another way. How would you download a file via angular. The file doesn't actually reside on the server, we only have the file content as a Stream

Comment: I don't think it's possible to download file with $http.get, you could use `window.open` or a hidden `iframe` with src pointing to the url to download the file

Comment: The problem I have with using window.open is I can append the X-XSRF-TOKEN header. Any ideas, secure agaisnt Corss Site Request Forgery. Do I have to temporarily store the file on server side and send back a unique reference id or something. What is best-practice?